# Create Liquid shooting from bottle in Blender 2.91

Tags: animation, particles, fluid-simulation

I followed several tutorials, but none seem to generate any liquid.  I am using 2.91.2 on OS 11.

I have a cube set up as a liquid domain and a disk set as fluid Inflow.

(see below).

The problem is that nothing happens when I bake.  It generates the bake without any particles.  I followed multiple tutorials.  I am using Eevee, but that should be okay.  Any suggestions appreciated.

One thing I noticed is that layout of the Fluid section differs slightly than ALL of the tutorials I have seen.  For example, flow type and flow behavior are two different dropdowns, and other subtle differences.

I got some of this working, but have two questions....

How do I hide the domain when it is NOT animating?
There are colored spheres showing up in my fluid.... not sure why.

[image: Ugly Domain]

[image: Blue and Green spheres]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: Okay, the differences are caused by the fact that I am using Mantaflow which is new.  I got that.

I think the fluid was NOT working because it was too small.  

HOWEVER, now the domain is showing up when the item is not animating.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the cache bake type to all:

This is what you have:
[image]

You need to change the type to all instead of modular:
[image]

Then you bake.

(I would also suggest you change the resolution to something in between 64 and 256 (Depending on how good your PC is))

Let me know if it works
Daniel

Comment: It worked.  Baking all did resolve most of the issue.  I just found it awkward to HIDE the domain until it is animated, make it visible during the animation and then hide it once done.  I would think that we could set it up, soft of like "Hide emitter" to hide the domain (but show anything animated within said domain).  Maybe there is, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did resolve this doing the following:
I kept everything At replay...It seemed to work, but I did notice some delay.  The next one I will do all.

I had to keyframe the rendering of the domain and the flow source to prevent them from showing when I didn't want to.  I hope there is a better way.

The size of the source and particles DOES matter as a few tutorials have shown.  It is bit difficult and took more trial and error than I would like, but it worked.

I Need to figure out how to keep the water on the screen longer... it disappears which does not make sense. There is no outflow, but I will look at some additional settings.

Overall, very cool.